# Совмещение Back to Top и Фона на всю страницу на CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сверстал два эффекта которые позволяют:

1. Стандартная кнопка Back to Top ("Наверх") из соц. сети ВКонтакте, которая позволяет вернуться на вверх старицы. ([исходная страница](http://1hd.com.ua/vk/index1.html))
2. Второй эффект позволяет фоновому изображению быть развернутым на весь и стоять на месте в то время как прокручивание скрола уводит текст вверх/вниз (код на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pdtb2/), [исходная страница](http://1hd.com.ua/vk/index2.html)).

   Не могу уже неделю соединить эти два эффекта в один живой организм. Как только подключаю события, селекторы перестает работать тот или иной эффект.

Comment: Опять этот вопрос :D

Comment: тебе смешно а я уже в без выходном положении еще один деень про...н и у меня с этим не чего не получилось.

Comment: вот зачем столько кода тут????

Comment: если у вас получиться уменьшить его буду только рад.

Comment: @Виталий Деревянко, пока Ваш документ не будет [валиден](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F1hd.com.ua%2Fvk%2Findex1.html&charset=windows-1251&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3), никто смотреть не будет.

Comment: А вам не подходит вариант сделать фон через background-size: cover ?

Comment: background-size: cover  не разу не делал скиььте пример. К-стати как сделать документ валидным и что это вообще такое?

Comment: @Виталий Деревянко, это означает то, что внутренее представление документа соответствует всем правилам и условиям, указаным в оффициальном референсе для текущего DOCTYPE. Посмотрите ссылку, что я представил в предыдущем комментарии. Там указаны все ошибки + описания.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ - первая часть этой статьи. Вот тут кажется перевод: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=807 Решение отличное и элегантное, но не кроссбраузерное. Но думаю, что если продолжить копать, то найдется либо качественная деградация (вставка чего попроще для браузеров, которые не могу), либо какое-нибудь допиливание.

Answer (score 1):

Вешайте Back to Top на див ваш с классом 'box' (ведь именно от прокручивается), а то у вас то наверно на body или window он повешен. Если не получиться, то напишите только код который вашу кнопку "Наверх" обрабатывает.

Comment: Андрей вот что получилось http://1hd.com.ua/vk/index3.html но появляться две проблемы. кросбраузерность первого эффекта начинает хромать везде кроме FireFoxa. и в придачу не пойму почему  CSS код который отвечает за растягивание wrappera растягивает фон. вот этот кусок <div style="margin:0 auto; width:85%; height:185.7em; background:
 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
        text